# Smart Contracts - How to agree on a value between parties?

Tags: cryptography, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

I am writing a smart contract in Solidity about co-selling an NFT.
When initializing the contract, a division for the benefits is chosen by one of the co-seller. For example, three co-seller could choose 50%, 25%, 25%.

My goal is that each co-seller must agree on the division value before the selling can take place. As I want to do it "on-chain", I'm wondering what is the best way to do it.

- Include a function in the smart contract that set an "agreed" boolean for each co-seller
- Ask the co-seller to sign the current repartition and send it to the smart contract
- Other

As a bonus, I'm also wondering what to do in case of a disagreement. Is there any known pattern for negotiation of values "on-chain" ?

Thanks in advance for your answers :)

Answer (score 0):

let me give this a shot:

```
contract NFT_Price_Agreement {

    bool reachedAgreement = false;    
    uint numParties = 3;
    uint numSigned = 0;
    uint totalVal = 0;

    uint nftPrice = 1000000000000000000; // = 1 ether

    mapping(address => uint) public nftStake;

    function makeReq(uint reqStake) public {
        uint stake = nftPrice * (reqStake / 100);
        totalVal += stake; //  to make sure 100% ownership at the end
        nftStake[msg.sender] = stake;
        numSigned++;
    }

    function confirmReq() public {
        require(numSigned == numParties, "Not everyone has agreed on what percent ownership.");
        require(totalVal == nftPrice);
        reachedAgreement = true;
    }
}
```

While this will currently yield an error, this is the general idea. To abort request and make a new one, you will just have to have a function that restates what your mappings are to 0 for their requested stake and decrement 1 from numSigned. Even though this code has some issues, this is the general idea.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your input! If I understand correctly, your idea is to set a fixed price before the selling begin and then the sum of each user stake must correspond to the fixed price ? How would you approach the problem of not having a fixed price but rather make all owners agree on one ? (a trivial example is to take the average of price proposition for example)